# Displaying a value of a variable as text over an image

Tags: html, oracle-apex

So I am using the following code to place some text in various places over an image map

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#V4.png" usemap="#image-mapA">

<map name="image-mapA">

    <area target="" alt="Strategic" title="Strategic" href="" coords="8,63,223,266" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Planned" title="Planned" href="" coords="314,60,531,268" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Blackout" title="Blackout" href="" coords="608,63,823,267" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Tactical" title="Tactical" href="" coords="890,63,1098,267" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Inflight" title="Inflight" href="" coords="225,618,1140,693" shape="rect">

  <div class="strategic">26 February 2019</div>
  <div class="planned">26 December 2018</div>
  <div class="blackout">13 September 2018</div>
  <div class="inflight">Next available forum: <b>13 September 2018</b></div>


</map>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is, instead of hard coding the dates in the divs, have them as variables that are read as the page loads.

For example the 'blackout' date would be calculated as

```
SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(SYSTIMESTAMP - (12 / 24), 'WED'), 'THU') + 7) 
  FROM DUAL;
```

How would I go about doing this?

At the moment I have an item call `P12_BLACKOUT` on the oracle apex page where the image map is displayed, but I cant seem to get the variable to display.

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you need to learn about APEX is [Substitution Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022). Shortly, there are two possible ways:

1. You generate the HTML code in a PL/SQL code. You can use parameter `:P1_BLACKOUT` in your calculations, APEX will automatically use its value in the code.
2. You use an HTML code as static content of the region (it looks like it is your case). You can use the value of the item as `&P1_BLACKOUT.`. In this case:

   - Put your calculation into a Before Header process:

     ```
     SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(SYSTIMESTAMP - (12 / 24), 'WED'), 'THU') + 7) 
       into :P1_BLACKOUT
       FROM DUAL;
     ```
   - Write your static HTML as:

     ```
     ...<div class="blackout">&P1_BLACKOUT.</div>...
     ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did as you suggested but I am getting the following error ORA-20001: Unable to bind P12_BLACKOUT_DATE verify length of item is 30 bytes or less. Use v() syntax to reference items longer than 30 bytes. ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist

Comment: "bind variable does not exist" - It looks like a typo in the name of the item, check it once again.

Comment: Confirmed it is there https://i.imgur.com/CB1ClhG.png and this is the query in the computation `SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(SYSTIMESTAMP - (12 / 24), 'WED'), 'THU') + 7) 
  into :P12_BLACKOUT_DATE
  FROM DUAL;`